# Twilio: How do I mark a message as a response to another message?

Tags: twilio

I'm new to twilio/twilml and was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to send message to a user and having a response be tagged to that message.

e.g.,

Twil -> User: "Reply DOG to this message"

User -> Twil: "DOG other stuff"

Does twilio recognize that "DOG other stuff" is in response to "Reply DOG to this message". If not, is there a parameter that I can set so that I can recognize a text is response to a message that the server has sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies to keep track of conversations in SMS. Twilio has a good write up of using cookies here https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/07/the-definitive-guide-to-sms-conversation-tracking.html

I have a TaskRouter demo app that uses cookies to track an SMS conversation so that it will not route an SMS through TaskRouter if it's part of an active conversation.  You can do the same by creating and storing a "conversation" and passing the key to that conversation in the cookie. https://github.com/bcoyle73/client-acd/blob/master/client-acd.rb#L170

Comment: That's an awesome use of TaskRouter to make that happen, I'd not thought of using it for that. Thanks for sharing!